# Pass a variable to language file without sprintf

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to pass a variable to a language file. I have created `MY_language.php` in `application/core/MY_language.php`.

```
class MY_Language extends CI_Lang
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function line($line, $params = null)
    {
        $return = parent::line($line);

        if ($return === false) {
            return "!-- $line --!";
        } else {
            if (!is_null($params)) {
                $return = $this->_ni_line($return, $params);
            }
            return $return;
        }
    }

    private function _ni_line($str, $params)
    {
        $return = $str;

        $params = is_array($params) ? $params : array($params);

        $search = array();
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            $search[$cnt] = '/\\$' . ($cnt + 1) . '/';
            $cnt++;
        }

        $return = preg_replace($search, $params, $return);

        return $return;
    }
}
```

This file must override the CodeIgniter `line()` function and accept an array of parameters as input, and insert into string language everywhereIi have type `$` in my language text.

```
$lang['delete'] = "$name was deleted";
```

The result of the above code is:

```
sam was deleted
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in codeigniter 3  the language your core language file must be PREFIX_lang
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding parameters to the `line()` function you are unable to override it.

Use a different name like `magic_line()`